# TFS 2015 Rest API - Create Build Definition

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to create a build definition in TFS using his api rest for it.

[This is the microsoft docs for TFS Api Rest](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0)

I get status code 200 but...

[This is what i get when I look into Tfs build definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpHWz.png)

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: your first link needs login.

Comment: this is the right link https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#create-a-build-definition

Comment: That looks more like an issue with your browser than with the build definition.

Comment: It's not, cause the others build definitions are normal

Comment: only definitions that I made by api rest, are with issues

Comment: Could you share your detailed rest api?

Answer (score 0):

Your second link provided a screenshot that a build definition with no tasks. It seems you had created a build definition successfully, but you didn't add tasks in the build definition.

Check your rest api to see whether you have `"build": []` parameter with `"task"` in it as the following example shows:

```
 "build": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Build solution **\\*.sln",
      "task": {
        "id": "71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "solution": "**\\*.sln",
        "msbuildArgs": "",
        "platform": "$(platform)",
        "configuration": "$(config)",
        "clean": "false",
        "restoreNugetPackages": "true",
        "vsLocationMethod": "version",
        "vsVersion": "latest",
        "vsLocation": "",
        "msbuildLocationMethod": "version",
        "msbuildVersion": "latest",
        "msbuildArchitecture": "x86",
        "msbuildLocation": "",
        "logProjectEvents": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Test Assemblies **\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
      "task": {
        "id": "ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "testAssembly": "**\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
        "testFiltercriteria": "",
        "runSettingsFile": "",
        "codeCoverageEnabled": "true",
        "otherConsoleOptions": "",
        "vsTestVersion": "14.0",
        "pathtoCustomTestAdapters": ""
      }
    }
  ],
```